# Connect Wordpress comment moderation with bbPress Moderation plugin

Tags: bbpress, moderation

Is it possible to connect the bbPress Moderation plugin with WordPress's first comment moderation so a Wordpress comment moderation would also approve people for the forum, and a moderated first topic/reply on the forum would approve someone for wordpress comments...?

To keep people from having to be moderated twice...

Comment: What has been your research so far? Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you found and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and above all, it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer. More info about how to ask a good question can be found on the [ask] page.

Comment: Spent hours searching everywhere, no answers, nor even references to the possibility, though it seems (is to me) a very useful sort of plugin to have, something similar to the bbpress moderation plugin that would tie in with wordpress' first comment moderation option, so one moderation for either place would do for the whole site, just as registering is for the whole site, both wordpress and bbpress. Be nice to also have a referral to an info page option, and not show comment, reply or topic, or let any more be posted, until moderated. In case someone is inspired. I'm code illiterate or... :-)

Comment: Please: Always add information as [edit] to your question.